# Page headers in frontmatter in wrong order when using landscaped table

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, landscape, front-matter

I'm using a landscaped table in my frontmatter but the page header info is mangled. The page headers for the example below are

*i - \null*

*ii - CONTENTS*

*iii - \null*

*iv - **CONTENTS** (This is the problem one)*

*1 - \null*

*2 - CHAPTER 1. CHAP 1*

*etc.*

but should (I think) be as follows:

*i - \null*

*ii - CONTENTS*

*iii - \null*

*iv - **TABLE***

*1 - \null*

*2 - CHAPTER 1. CHAP 1*

*etc.*

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,numbers=noenddot]{book}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\chapter*{Table}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table}
\begin{table*}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ l l  }
            r1c1 & r1c2 \\
            r2c1 & r2c2 \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table*}
\end{landscape}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Chap 1}
\chapter{Chap 2}
\chapter{Chap 3}
\chapter{Chap 4}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: try `\chapter*{Table}
\markboth{TABLE}{TABLE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table}`

Comment: this not because of oriantation but this is the case of starred chapters.